# Missing dialogue options when talking to Sofus the Bull in "The Play's the Thing"

Tags: the-witcher-3

I am currently in Novigrad, doing the quest "The Play's The Thing". I am stuck at the part of "Head to the docks and hire ushers for the play". I have already met Sofus The Bull, who, from my understanding, is who I need to talk to in order to organize the fight to prove my worth so they will work for me and keep peace at the play.

Though after I challenged the man his next line was "Made up your mind, ready to take part in the next fight of the century" but then the next line from the Sofus The Bull is: "Unless you have found your, Uh, Ushers, For, Uh... Whatsit." and then Geralt's only response is "Lemme think about it." which then ends the dialogue.

I cannot move along in this quest without getting the ushers and I have looked online for help but it seems no one else has ever run into the same problem. I have also tried different times of day but it seems to have no effect. Is there something or someone else I have to see before I fight this man?

Comment: Hello Mad_Inferno, welcome to Arqade. Take a look at the [tour] and [help]. Good first question. I have edited it a bit to break up the long block of text, and changed the title to be more descriptive. Don't worry, this is perfectly normal on this site. If I messed up something, feel free to [edit] again or roll back via the [edit history](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/261383/revisions) (you can normally get there by clicking on "edited X ago").

Comment: For this reason I always save a lot, and make sure to keep an older save before starting a new quest. When such a major bug happens, I'll just load that "failsafe save" and hope for the best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happened to me, and here's how I solved it.

The option to proceed doesnt actually appear unless you have approx. 240 crowns. If you don't have the coin, the option simply will not appear. All you will get is "Lemme think about it".

Just sell a few items to gain the extra coin, and an addtional option to proceed will be there.