# Quest complete cheat

Tags: the-witcher-3

I need to do this to move on in the game, and I am willing to do anything...

But I was wondering, is there any possible way to 'cheat' the game and complete a quest in The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt? I will do anything in order to complete this quest including using other means than completing it legitimately, because I am unable to do so because of a bug. The quest in hand is `The Play's The Thing` and if you want to read my problem, it is [a separate question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/261383/missing-dialogue-options-when-talking-to-sofus-the-bull-in-the-plays-the-thing) on this arqade account.

However, a solution for all quests might be more useful for other people with a similar problem.

As I said, any solution will do, whether that means installing a client or modding the game files. I have already tried console commands, but every source I have looked at does not seem to give commands that directly affect quests (e.g. finish.current_quest).

Comment: There were a few quests that I just gave up on, because either I had hit some strange little glitch, or I just couldn't figure out the precise series of steps in just the right way. Abandoning those handful of quests didn't seem to diminish the game all that much for me.

Comment: @Bryan problem is, this specific quest OP can't complete is part of the main quest so abandoning it means no way to finish the game.

Comment: I see you got your answer on the bug and I assume you have gotten past the quest at this point. As far as I know there is no way to 'Cheat' your way past a quest in The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt. The developers would generally have to develop a command to specifically do this and  I doubt they did this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do that.

You can try load another save or auto save before you activate that specifc quest.

But the answer in the [post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/261383/missing-dialogue-options-when-talking-to-sofus-the-bull-in-the-plays-the-thing) that you mentioned is perfectly valid. Didn't work?

Comment: Understandably this is impossible, the question that this refers to was solved leaving my problem obsolete